# How can I get the highest element in a CMake list?

Tags: list, cmake, max

I have a CMake list (literally or in a variable), and I want to obtain the list item with the maximum value. How should I do this?

Note: The list is not necessarily sorted, nor necessarily duplicate-free.

Comment: is this only about comparing numbers? Or are non-numeric strings included? your self-answer only supports numeric strings I think, but your question has no such constraint...

Answer (score 1):

Starting CMake version 3.18 you should be able to use `list(SORT)` for getting a sorted list of elements making it simple to extract the maximum one. Perhaps not as efficient as a search through a list, but for the expected input sizes probably makes little difference:

```
function(max_element OUT_VAR)
    list(SORT ARGN COMPARE NATURAL ORDER DESCENDING)
    list(GET ARGN 0 MAX_ELEMENT)
    set(${OUT_VAR} ${MAX_ELEMENT} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

max_element(MAX 10 4 19 1)
message("MAX = ${MAX}") # prints "MAX = 19"
```

Comment: Well, it's shorter code than my linear search, but... can't I do better than that?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike most likely not. Sorting integers isn't something that's used often build systems, at least not in the files uses as input for the program doing the build. Even with this approach technically we're sorting version numbers, not integers; we're just making use of the special case where all "version numbers" have exactly 1 component.

Comment: It is actually not uncommon to want to choose among different options when building: Versions of a dependency, for example; or oldest/newest architecture of a CPU or GPU on the system; etc. While CMake tends to make the assumption that "the first thing I see is the only relevant thing", that's a bit artificial.

Comment: Why do we use `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)` rather than `return(PROPAGATE .... )`?

Comment: @einpoklum Both seem to be equivalent in most cases. `return(PROPAGATE)` is a relatively recent addition to cmake (Version 3.25). If you're the cmake versions used with your project are suitable for use of `return(PROPAGATE)` there seems little reason not to change this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a CMake command that gets you the maximum element, but you can write your own function for getting this:

```cmake
function(max out_var)
    list(GET ARGN 0 ${out_var})
    list(SUBLIST ARGN 1 -1 tail)
    foreach(val ${tail})
        if (${val} GREATER ${out_var})
            set(${out_var} ${val})
        endif()
    endforeach()
    return(PROPAGATE ${out_var})
endfunction()
```

You invoke it like so:

```cmake
max(out1 1 2 3 5 4 5 3)
# out1 is now "5"
set(my_list 7 3 5)
max(out2 ${my_list})
# out2 is now "7"
```

Further reading:

- CMake's [`list` commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html)
- Writing CMake [functions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html)
- CMake's [`return` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/return.html#command:return)